# Get child terms of current term of the current post

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

I have custom post type "product" and taxonomy is "product_cat". There are two child terms -Music and videos.
Under Music i have two more child terms albums and single.
Now when i go to music category i want to get all the child terms of the music. I am using the following code

```
<?php $page_id = get_the_id(); ?>

<?php $cat_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $page_id, 'product_cat' ); ?>

<pre><?php var_dump($cat_terms); ?></pre>


<?php foreach ($cat_terms as $terms  ) {?>
<?php $array = (array) $terms; ?>
<section id="engagement-rings">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="display-rings">
          <div class="heading-img text-center"><?php echo $array["name"]; ?></div>
          <div class="engagement rings-list clearfix">
            <ul class="list-unstyled clearfix">
            <?php
                   $args = array( 'post_type'=>'product',
                  'tax_query' => array(

                    array(
                      'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                      'field' => 'slug',
                      'terms' => $array["name"],
                    )
                  )
                );
                $postslist = get_posts( $args );


              ?>
                <?php foreach ($postslist as $post) : ?>
                    <?php $array1 = (array) $post; ?>

                    <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'shop_thumbnail' ); ?>
                    <li><a href=""><img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt=""></a></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="view-all">View all</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<?php } ?>
```

But this is giving me the Music category and one child i.e albums . But i just want album and single .

Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should rather use [`get_queried_object()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) to return the current page's term. From there you should get the taxonomy name, term ID and the parent.

Now here is my logic on this. Whenever you are on a parent term, ie. *music* or *videos*, the parent will return `0`. You can use this to execute the code only if you are on a parent term page.

Here is the output from `var_dump($cat_terms);` on a child page

```
array(0) {
}
```

and here is from a parent page

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(119)
  [1]=>
  int(120)
}
```

119 and 120 is the child terms of my parent term

You have the taxonomy name and term ID, so you can use [`get_term_children`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children) to get the child terms from your terms *music* or *videos*. Like I said, you would only want to do this on the parent page. But that is all up to you.

Here is the code

```
<?php 
    $queried_object = get_queried_object('term');
        $tax = $queried_object->taxonomy;
        $term = $queried_object->term_id;
        $parent = $queried_object->parent;

    if( 0 == $parent ) {
        $cat_terms = get_term_children( $term, $tax );
         ?>
           <pre><?php var_dump($cat_terms); ?></pre>
         <?php 
        //<---DO SOMETHING ON PARENT TERM PAGE--->
    }else{
        //<---DO SOMETHING ON CHILD TERM PAGE
    }
?>
```

Comment: My pleasure. Glad I could help. Enjoy :-)